# how to give a user privilege to run Ansible commands or just an specific tag?

Tags: ansible, linux, permissions

for example, I have a tag named 'installagent' and i want to run this command `ansible -playbook -i /path  agent.yml --tags installagent` from another server via ssh on my Ansible server with user 'testusr'. what should i do?

can i limit 'testusr' to only use specific tags?
( I read somewhere that i should give `sudo` permission to that user. if its true what should i do if i don't want to give `sudo` permission?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool in Ansible to authorize a user to execute selected commands or tags only.

It seems a good idea to use sudo to authorize [user to execute selective commands](https://superuser.com/questions/767415/limit-user-to-execute-selective-commands-linux).